# Why is gravity not counted as acceleration in this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

I am doing physics homework and I noticed that the solution to this question specifies that the total vertical Force is 0. Since the two buckets (shown below) are hanging vertically, wouldn't I just assume that gravity is the acceleration? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: The total vertical force is zero because the sum of the gravitational force $m \textbf g$ and the other force $\textbf F$ sum up to zero. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: One possible source of your confusion may stem from a very common habit of beginning students.  That is to refer to $g$ as "gravity".  $g$ is the *acceleration due to gravity*.  If the thing is not moving, there is no acceleration.  There is, however, gravity.  It manifests as the force of attraction between two bodies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I missing?

$g$ is the acceleration *[if the body is freely falling](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-5/Acceleration-of-Gravity)*.  But these aren't freely falling.  Indeed, it is specified that they are at rest.

Comment: So I can only use gravity for acceleration if the object is in free fall? Thanks!

Comment: @Ghost Koi - Yes, and note that for a body with multiple forces acting on it, the $F$ in $F=ma$ must be the *total* force (the [vector sum](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-1/Vector-Addition) of all the individual forces). Once you have that, you can calculate the body's acceleration by $a=F/m$, and it will be $g$ near Earth's surface *if* gravity is the only force acting on the body, since the gravitational force is always $mg$ for a body near the Earth's surface (regardless of whether it's in freefall or not).

Answer (score 1):

Gravity certainly *would* accelerate these buckets ... *if* those ropes weren't there. However, since those ropes are there providing a force upward, and gravity provides the force downward, then one of two things can happen:

1. The buckets travel downward (or even upward) at a constant velocity, or
2. They stay put.

In either case, the acceleration is zero because all of the forces balance out. Furthermore, in *this* particular problem the buckets aren't going anywhere because the problem explicitly states that they aren't moving. That means a = 0 and v = 0. Also, as a reality check: the top bucket's rope works about 2x as hard to keep all of the buckets from falling, while as the bottom bucket's rope only has to worry about keeping one bucket from falling.